# Black lines above and below searchController.searchBar with custom tint

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, searchbar, bartintcolor

[image]

If you are seeing black lines like in the image above when using

```
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = YOUR_COLOR
```

try UISearchBarStyle.Minimal to make them disappear.

```
 searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
```

[image]

Reported as bug 22668614.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround included in original post.